# count and sum number of days in date ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
id | start_date  |  end_date  | client_id
1    2013-08-01    2013-08-09       1
2    2013-08-10    2013-08-10       1
3    2013-08-10    2013-08-17       1
4    2013-08-18    2013-08-18       1
5    2013-08-18    2013-08-18       1
6    2013-08-18    2013-08-31       1
7    2013-08-01    2013-08-09       2
8    2013-08-11    2013-08-11       2
9    2013-08-11    2013-08-17       2
10   2013-08-19    2013-08-20       2
```

what I'm trying to do is count the number of days that each client was present without repeating the days for each client, so from the previous data I'm looking to get:

```
client_id | total_days
    1           31
    2           18
```

So for client `1` I get 31 because he was "present" for 31 days, from 8/1/2013 - 8/31/2013 with no gaps, and for client `2` I get 18 because he was present for 18 days:

```
8/1 - 8/9 = 9 days 
8/11 - 8/17 = 7 days 
8/19 - 8/20 = 2 days
```

is there anyway to achieve this in MySQL, I've been trying for a while but have no idea on how to do it.

This is the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b064a/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If overlapping ranges exist, then I suggest building a driver table that is a list of dates, then `JOIN` to that table using `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT a.Client_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT b.Date)
FROM YourTable a
JOIN Dates b
  ON b.Date BETWEEN a.start_date  AND a.end_date
GROUP BY a.Client_ID
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9162d/4/0)

There are plenty of places to find calendar table logic, [here's one.](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)

If ranges never overlap then you can use `SUM(DATEDIFF())`.

Comment: Is this solution still viable even for years worth of data?

Comment: Sure thing, you can index the date fields to help performance, but even a century worth of dates isn't very many records, the date table could be created in memory too.

Comment: I think the calendar table might be the only answer since the date ranges do overlap. I just feel uneasy about the fact that even if I create a calendar table for 100 years, then in a 100 years (yea right) it would need updating or the query wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: You could use min/max to create your date table dynamically that always encompasses the full relevant time period.

Comment: @SOfanatic The good news is that most script available online to build calendar tables will allow you to change the values you want for start and end dates so you can make a 1000 year table if you want, though my guess is you won't even be using MySQL 20 years from now, so unless you are dealing with calendar dates well out into the future, you shouldn't have problems with a 20-50 year calender.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no overlapping ranges. You can use the following query:

```
SELECT Client_id,
       Sum(DATEDIFF(End_date, Start_date)) AS `Present`
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Client_id;
```

This will give you an overview of the number of days a client was present.